# Capture current scrollbar position vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scrollbar, tabcontrol

Im trying to capture the position of a tabcontrol scrollbar. However this is proving somewhat difficult. the ultimate Aim is to reposition the scrollbar position  by daaing the current position with the size of a new row of items which is 105 thus New position = (old position + 105).

Im using winform vb.net

Comment: A TabControl usually doesn't have a ScrollBar.  Are you referring to a TabPage?  If so, check its AutoScrollPosition property for the Y value.

Comment: `Dim CURPOS As Integer = TabPage1.scrollbar.value
Dim NEWPOS As Integer = (CURPOS + 105)
TabPage1.scrollbar.value = (NEWPOS)` ???

Comment: LarsTech is right this is one of the TabPages of the TabControl. You should be accessing Vertical/Horizontal scrolls, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented above, you mean the `TabPage` (`TabPage1` in the codes below). You have two options:

a) Using the standard `.Value` property (for both `VerticalScroll` and `HorizontalScroll`). Sample:

```
TabPage1.VerticalScroll.Value = TabPage1.VerticalScroll.Value + 105
```

Note that the Y values start on top and thus +105 means that the vertical scroll is moved downwards.

b) Using the `ScrollControlIntoView` method. Sample:

```
TabPage1.ScrollControlIntoView(Panel1)
```

Where `Panel1` can be replaced with any control contained by `TabPage1`; both scrollbars (horizontal and vertical) would be moved such that the given control (`Panel1` in this case) would become completely visible.

Comment: I see however this is to be coded\ assigned to a button cause I dont want visible scrollbars on my tabpage (for my requierments they look ghastly) prob though now is that I cant hide my scrollbars in my tabpage

Comment: @Argon To a button? I don't understand what you mean. This code controls the behaviour of the scrollbars as you requested. Making them visible or not is a different story. Also note that this code (or any other one) can be triggered more or less automatically (e.g., from one of the events associated with the TabControl/TabPage; or as you proposed in your question: when a new row is added to the given control) or via user intervention (e.g., a button click); but this is not related to your question either. Can you please explain better what you meant?

Comment: Im making an app which heavaly relies on a UI asphetic, the scrollbars just dont go :) `Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        '---If the number of buttons is equal or more then 25...
        Dim BTNCOUNT As Integer = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Count
        If BTNCOUNT >= 25 Then

            TabControl1.SelectedTab.VerticalScroll.Value = TabControl1.SelectedTab.VerticalScroll.Value + 110

        Else

            MsgBox("Nothing to scroll")

        End If

    End Sub`

Comment: @Argon As said, the proposed code deals with the position of the scrollbar (as you requested), not with its visibility. If you don't want the scrollbars to be visible (unless when used), you should affect the  `AutoScroll` property. That is:  `TabPage1.AutoScroll = False` at the start and `TabPage1.AutoScroll = True` in the button (before affecting the `Value` property). This isn't exactly related to your original question; but, in any case, you should add any code to the question, not via comments.

Comment: @Argon No problem. Here to help.